# My dropdown list using bootstrap multiselect not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to create a multiselect dropdown list using the bootstrap javascript and css files.  Unfortunately, my dynamically created set of options (using AJAX) does not appear to be populating the list.

I know it must be related to the multiselect feature because when I set it up as a single-select dropdown, it works great.

I wonder if it is related to when this function is called.  The list is not called when the document is ready, but rather after the ajax call succeeds.

Here is the code:

```js
function Participants(sid){
    console.log(sid);
    $('#participants').empty()
     $('#participants').append("<option>Loading......</option>");
    $.ajax({ 
           method:"POST",
           url:"participants_dropdown.php?sid="+sid,
           contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType:"json",
           success: function(data){
           console.log('success')
           $('#participants').empty();
           $('#participants').append("<option value='0'>---Select Participants---</option>");
           $.each(data, function(i, item){
                  $('#participants').append('<option value="'+data[i].facility_id+'">Call-Sign: '+data[i].call_sign+' - Operator: '+data[i].operator+' - Primary Programming: '+data[i].primary_programming+'</option>');
                  });
           },
           complete: function(){
           }
           });
    $('#participants').multiselect('destroy');
    $('#participants').multiselect();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>





<div class="col-md-4">
<h3><span>2) Select Market Participants</span></h3>
<select id="participants" multiple class="form-control">
</select>
</div>


<!---sample JSON
[{"operator":"Nexstar Media Group Inc","owner":"Mission Broadcasting Inc","call_sign":"KRBC-TV","facility_id":"306","primary_programming":"NBC"},{"operator":"Nexstar Media Group Inc","owner":"Nexstar Media Group Inc","call_sign":"KTAB-TV","facility_id":"59988","primary_programming":"CBS"},{"operator":"Prime Time Christian Broadcasting Incorporated","owner":"Prime Time Christian Broadcasting Incorporated","call_sign":"KPCB-DT","facility_id":"77452","primary_programming":"REL"},{"operator":"Sinclair Broadcast Group Inc","owner":"Sinclair Broadcast Group Inc","call_sign":"KTXS-TV","facility_id":"308","primary_programming":"ABC"},{"operator":"TEGNA Inc","owner":"TEGNA Inc","call_sign":"KXVA","facility_id":"62293","primary_programming":"FOX"}]--->
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.  I have tried various solutions suggested in similar posts but no luck.

Comment: may you add the value you get in ajax success: console.log(data)?

Comment: Here is what I get (for the first two):     0:
call_sign: "KRBC-TV"
facility_id: "306"
operator: "Nexstar Media Group Inc"
owner: "Mission Broadcasting Inc"
primary_programming: "NBC"
__proto__: Object
1:
call_sign: "KTAB-TV"
facility_id: "59988"
operator: "Nexstar Media Group Inc"
owner: "Nexstar Media Group Inc"
primary_programming: "CBS"
__proto__: Object "  As I said, I am able to successfully populate a single dropdown list, so may be something with the way multi-select works.

Comment: Please, stringify:  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: Added to original question the json response

Answer (score 1):

In your Participants function you have an ajax call. Because this is an asynchronous call you need to move the destroy and create **multiselect** inside the success fragment:

```
function Participants(sid){
     console.log(sid);
     $('#participants').empty()
     $('#participants').append("<option>Loading......</option>");
     $.ajax({
         method:"POST",
         url:"participants_dropdown.php?sid="+sid,
         contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType:"json",
         success: function(data){
             console.log('success')
             $('#participants').multiselect('destroy');
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ HERE
             $('#participants').empty();
             $('#participants').append("<option value='0'>---Select Participants---</option>");
             $.each(data, function(i, item){
                 $('#participants').append('<option value="'+data[i].facility_id+'">Call-Sign: '+data[i].call_sign+' - Operator: '+data[i].operator+' - Primary Programming: '+data[i].primary_programming+'</option>');
          });
             $('#participants').multiselect();
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ HERE
         },
         complete: function(){
         }
     });
 }
```

The snippet (the button simulates the ajax call):

```js
$('#participants').empty()
$('#participants').append("<option>Loading......</option>");
$('#participants').multiselect();


$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var data = [{"operator":"Nexstar Media Group Inc","owner":"Mission Broadcasting Inc","call_sign":"KRBC-TV","facility_id":"306","primary_programming":"NBC"},{"operator":"Nexstar Media Group Inc","owner":"Nexstar Media Group Inc","call_sign":"KTAB-TV","facility_id":"59988","primary_programming":"CBS"},{"operator":"Prime Time Christian Broadcasting Incorporated","owner":"Prime Time Christian Broadcasting Incorporated","call_sign":"KPCB-DT","facility_id":"77452","primary_programming":"REL"},{"operator":"Sinclair Broadcast Group Inc","owner":"Sinclair Broadcast Group Inc","call_sign":"KTXS-TV","facility_id":"308","primary_programming":"ABC"},{"operator":"TEGNA Inc","owner":"TEGNA Inc","call_sign":"KXVA","facility_id":"62293","primary_programming":"FOX"}];
    $('#participants').multiselect('destroy');
    $('#participants').empty();
    $('#participants').append("<option value='0'>---Select Participants---</option>");
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        $('#participants').append('<option value="'+data[i].facility_id+'">Call-Sign: '+data[i].call_sign+' - Operator: '+data[i].operator+' - Primary Programming: '+data[i].primary_programming+'</option>');
    });
    $('#participants').multiselect();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <h3><span>2) Select Market Participants</span></h3>
    <select id="participants" multiple class="form-control">
    </select>
    <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to respond.  Unfortunately it still does not work even after inserting the two multiselect lines to the suggested locations.  What is stranger is that I copied your example code (with the button below) and even that was not working....even though when I run the snippet on this page it works great.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What is also interesting is that my blank drop down list is not rendering the same way as yours.  It shows up as a blank box and the word "None Selected" does not appear.  Could it be related to other bootstrap files that I might have loaded on my server?

Comment: Take a look to the libs i used in the snippet

Comment: Figured it out.  First, on your code, I needed to move the javascript calling the button below the button itself.  In my code, after making your original changes (which solved my original problem), I also had to include the popper library and load that in before bootstrap.min.js.    Thank you very much for all your help.